# How can I generate voice as someone elses voice?

Tags: video, video-editor, audio, video-recording

I dont know if its possible but I would like to create voice similar to Gandalf from Lord of the rings. Is there some app or program which can help me? I know that I can use google translator but it is not same as human voice

Sorry if this question was asked before.

Comment: We don't do such app/service recommendations here. I doubt there is anything good to imitate voices of specific actors out there, anyway. I think some text-to-speech services offer a small selection of more realistic voices, if that's sufficient for you.

Comment: You could learn ho to imitate voices, record yourself and edit it, but you cannot magically turn your voice into someone else's withouth much effort. Maybe https://sound.stackexchange.com/ is more approriate for detailed voice imitation questions.

Comment: Just saw this. Nothing good can come of it.  Wondering how OP intends to use it?  Gandalf? Really? https://www.econotimes.com/Deepfake-Voice-Technology-The-Good-The-Bad-The-Future-1601278

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Real-time Voice Cloning](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning) for this purpose. The quality isn't great, but it works for US accented voices better than UK in my experience (Gandalf = Ian McKellen = English).  Maybe this would be better in [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/)?